# Validate email string after split

Tags: c#, validation

I have the following string:

```
var proc = new SAPayslips();
proc.RuleCustomValue = "document.xml|name@domain.com;name@domain.com;name@domain,co.za";
```

The first value is the name of a xml document, and the rest are emails I would like to utilize.

I can successfully split them and use them but I have a problem with the validation. I would like to throw an exception if the email address doesn't contain an @ char.

```
// retrieves document name
customValues = _ruleCustomValue.Split('|');
// retrieves emails
emails = customValues[1].Split(';');

if(!customValues[1].Contains("@"))
    throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Invalid Email adress,");
```

It doesn't throw the exception when there is no @

Comment: You are validating that *any* email contains a `@`, not that *each* email contains a `@`.

Comment: Is `co.za` in `name@domain.com;name@domain.com;name@domain,co.za` means an e-mail item? Since it's not separated by `;` but by `,`. Does it mean `name@domain,co.za` is an item or 2 items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check `emails` to search in array of *emails* instead of `customValues[1]` that is a string. Calling Contains on `customValues[1]` will return `true` if it contains only one `@`.

You need to iterate through array of find if any of array element does not contain @ in it.

```
foreach (var email in emails)
  if(!email.Contains("@"))
  { 
      throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Invalid Email adress,");
  }
```

You can also use linq, using [Enumerable.Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
if(emails.Any(email=>email.indexOf("@") == -1))
    throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Invalid Email adress,");
```

Comment: Maybe you mean `foreach` not just `for` (in code line 1)

Comment: Thanks @HeinzSiahaan.

Answer (score 2):

Checking whether or not there is "@" inside is not the exact solution for determining that it is an email adress, I think you are going to need regex pattern for this,

example;

```
function isEmail(email) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i);
    return pattern.test(email);
};
```

check it and throw an exception;

```
if( !isEmail("e@example.com") ) { *here we go! throw exception!*}
```

here more information about this; [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Email-address-validation-in-jQuery-using-Regular-Expressions.aspx)

I hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it will only throw this in one location (because you have only specified one location: `customValues[1]`)

Secondly, the item you have specified is actually the *second* item in the array, as all collections start at `0`.

What you may want to do instead is go through a loop, and check each email string:

```
foreach (string s in customValues)
{
    if (!s.Contains("@"))
        // throw exception
    else
        // do stuff...
}
```

Comment: It still remains NOT solved with this code since you just validate `name@domain.com;name@domain.com;name@domain,co.za` as an item and it will not throw error since it contains `@`. What you should do is get **each** e-mail and validate through it NOT the items in customValues.

Answer (score 0):

You are validating that any email contains a @, not that each email contains a @.

You should get each e-mail and validate through that each e-mail NOT for items in customvalues.

You can try this code:

```
// retrieves document name
        string[]customValues = _ruleCustomValue.Split('|');
        // retrieves emails
        string[] emails = customValues[1].Split(';');

        foreach (string email in emails)
        {
            if (!email.Contains("@"))
            {
                throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Invalid Email adress,");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// retrieves document name
customValues = _ruleCustomValue.Split('|');
// retrieves emails
emails = customValues[1].Split(';');
foreach(var email in emails)
{
    if (!EmailValidated(email))
    {
       throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Invalid Email adress,");
    }
}


private static bool EmailValidated(string emailAddress)
{
    const string pattern = @"^(([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))@"
                                   + @"((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?
                                        [0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\."
                                   + @"([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?
                                        [0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
                                   + @"([a-zA-Z]+[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$";
    var match = Regex.Match(emailAddress.Trim(), pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return match.Success;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your solution: what that very long RegEx pattern means?